# Save Base64 string to jpg on IFS (in RPGLE)

Tags: image, base64, jpeg, rpgle

I have an RPGLE variable that contains a BASE64 string of an image.  Does anyone know how I can save that data on the IFS as a jpg?

Comment: you're talking about the language RPG from IBM? I retagged the question for you, because the IFS tag is for something different and therefore misleading here.

Answer (score 2):

Before saving to the IFS as suggested by @jtaylor___

You'll need to decode the BASE64 string back into a binary value.

Scott comes to the rescue again with [Base64 Encode/Decode for ILE RPG](https://www.scottklement.com/base64/)

Also available are the [Apache Portable Runtime (APR) base64 routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaie/apr_core_api/group___a_p_r___util___base64.html)

Once you have the binary data in a variable, you can write it out to the IFS with JPG extension...

Comment: True about decoding first.  I use Scott's library for encoding.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Scott Klement's "Working with the IFS in RPG IV" (https://www.scottklement.com/rpg/ifs_ebook/).  It should be a simple matter of using the write() method to file with a JPG extension.